# C program in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studio. I'm trying to run Hello World, but am getting several errors and cannot figure out what the problem is.
I typed:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello World");


}
```

---

into a code file with .c extension. I get this:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup   
d:\Users\...\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj)    Project

Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   
d:\users\...Project.exe 1   1   Project
```

Anyone know what the problem is?
Thanks.

Comment: please reformat your code :~)

Comment: Actually, it should work if it's in a .c file that's being compiled as C code. How are you compiling?

Comment: Have you pasted the code from Visual Studio - I suspect there's some difference, since the code in your question compiles (and runs).

Comment: Type some garbage in the source code and verify that you get a compile error.  If you don't then you forgot to add the file to your project.

Comment: oh, you are right. i did "save as" when changing the src file from C++ to C, and it didn't save it in the project. that was the problem. thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compiles fine... you need to set it to compile as C code:

**Project->Properties->Advanced->Compile As C Code (/TC flag)**

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello World");


}
```

**Output:**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: main,
Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped
==========
```

**Reason:**

You are compiling as C code and therefore default int is not assumed in C++ code

**Update:**

As mentioned by **Michael Burr** your code should use a `*.c` extension. However, it will still compile cpp files as c code if you set the project properties. However, if no setting is provided it will compile with the default settings `(*.c -> c code)` and `(*.cpp -> cpp code)`.

Compiled as **C** code with **CPP** extension (successful)

```
1>------ Build started: Project: main, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>  main.vcxproj -> c:\users\shane\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\main\Debug\main.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Compiled as **CPP** code with **C** Extension (failed)

```
1>------ Build started: Project: main, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.c
1>c:\users\shane\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\main\main\main.c(4): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: If the code is in a .c file, VS should automatically compile it as C; also, if the code is compiled as C++ he'd be getting different errors (or earlier errors).

Answer (score 1):

There are two major problems with the code provided.  The first is that you did not add a header to be include after "include." Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

The second is that main needs a return type. Try:

```
int main()
{
   printf("Hello World");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: He does not need to modify his code... default int is assumed

Comment: `main()` doesn't need a return type in C - `int` is implicit (at least in C89/C90 which is what MSVC targets for C compiles).  Visual Studio doesn't event warn about the missing return type (or return statement) when compiled with warning level 3 (it gives a warning at level 4).

Comment: That said - what you've mentioned are definitely good suggestions and practices.

Comment: @martona: Nope; the C standard (at least, C99, §5.1.2.2.1) specifies clearly that *It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters [...] or with two parameters [...] `int argc, char *argv[]` [...] or in some other implementation-defined manner.* So anything that differs from the first two versions, although not forbidden, is not standard. However, what the OP wrote is not forbidden in C89 because `int` is assumed by default as the return type; however, default `int` was removed in C99.

Comment: @snmcdonald: you're perfectly right, and I knew that, so I specified that the default `int` is valid in C89; for the other quotation, I checked from a draft of the C89 standard that it's the same. I'm sorry if I've been pedant, but saying that `void main` is standard is plain wrong.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: Well, this was clearly about visual studio, and the answer I commented on had nothing to do with the OP's problem. What i wrote was correct in context.

Comment: @martona: it is correct plain `main()` works, but `void main()` is not standard, so you can't say that in general "it works in C". It was a remark just on the firs part of your comment.